# use ENV variable inside jwt sign

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, typegraphql

I am using JWT in my system and it pretty much works fine which I use a regular String for my **SecretKey** here is the working code

```
export class CompanyResolver {

  @Query(() => [Company])
  companies() {
    return Company.find();
  }

  @Query(() => Company)
  async login(
    @Arg("email") email: string,
    @Arg("password") password: string,
  ): Promise<Company | null> {
    const company = await Company.findOne({ where: { email } });

    if (!company)
      throw new Error("Company Not Found!!!");

    if (!await bcrypt.compare(password, company.password))
      throw new Error("Incorrect Password!!!");

    const secret=process.env.JWT_SECRET;  

    console.log(secret)

     company.accessToken = jsonwebtoken.sign({ company }, "12345", {
       expiresIn: "30 days"
     })
    return company;
  }
```

I have defined my secret in my **env** file which upon doing `console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET)`
does give me back my key which means there is not issue in that however the issue is when I try to use it

```
company.accessToken = jsonwebtoken.sign({ company }, secret, {
           expiresIn: "30 days"
         })
```

I get

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Secret'.
```

I'm a newbie to nodejs and TS I apologize in advance for any childish mistake, can someone point out the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`process.env` value type is `string | undefined`. This means Typescript is not guaranteeing you that there must be string type returned for every `process.env.MY_ENV_VAR`. It may possibly return `undefined` if the environment variable is not set, so, take your precaution.

In this case, something like this should help

```js
if(secret){
  company.accessToken = jsonwebtoken.sign({ company }, secret, {
           expiresIn: "30 days"
         })
} else {
  // Handle the case where the variable is not set, may be throw exception
}
```

Comment: thats unsual compared to other programming languages but definitely a good check by TS to handle an undefined error in case one comes up

Comment: @uneebmeer this is a runtime error, TS cant catch it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562164/how-to-make-typescript-throw-runtime-error

Answer (score 3):

You can also use definite assignment assertion to make typescript aware that the "secret" is certainly there by using an '!'. As the above answer mentions, process.env is of type string | undefined,  which is an invalid type for jwt.Secret.

```
company.accessToken = jsonwebtoken.sign({ company }, secret!, {
           expiresIn: "30 days"
         })
```

Comment: Although it silents the compiler warning it does not protect you from runtime error.